# How to make a Href link wait

Tags: javascript

I want to make a Clickable button, which waits 10 seconds to load the linked page. 
I was wondering if it also needs Href for it ?
If anyone know's how please help me out.

Comment: You would need to use javascript to implement the wait time before loading the new page.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the JS wait ? im sorta new to JS

Comment: Take a look at `setTimeout`

Comment: Are you want to make timer when seconds ticks finish then link appear ?

Comment: That sounds like a mean thing to do to your users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have tagged Javascript and not jQuery....

Something like

JavaScript:

```
function loadUrl(){
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Link:

```
<a href="JavaScript:setTimeout(loadUrl,10000)">Click My Link</a>
```

OR

JavaScript:

```
function delayUrlLoad(url, mils)
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = url;
    }, mils)
}
```

Link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="delayUrlLoad('http://www.google.com/', 10000);return false;"> Click Here </a>
```

Comment: clean & short :-) (and JS not jquery like OP asked)

Comment: It would be much cleaner without inline JS, or at the very least if the `setTimeout()` was inside the function.

Comment: @Fred maybe include a non-inline 2 ;-)

Comment: I don't like this solution very much, since you need to create a loadUrl kind of function for every link url, by the way -1 was not mine, you correctly didn't consider jquery

Comment: @abidibo now you don't

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs An optional parameter, yes that's a nice touch :)  I guess you could include a default URL too ;)  You could also accept seconds as the time parameter then times it by 1000 to give the milliseconds required by setTimeout.  Hopefully the OP (and anyone else that stumbles across this will get the idea and update it to their requirements :)

Comment: Well, it's still inline but still improvement :)

Answer (score 0):

How about?

**HTML:**

```
    <button id="yourbutton" href="https://www.google.com">
        Click Me
    </button>
```

**jQuery/JS:**

```
$( "#yourbutton" ).on( "click", function(event) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  setTimeout("loadPage(url)", 10000);
  event.preventDefault();
});

function loadPage(url){
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/wzb350na/1/)  (it wont load the new page in JSFiddle as it is sandboxed, but if you check console, it is indeed attempting to load the page after the timeout).

Comment: A part from the fact it uses jquery (same mine mistake) this is wrong, you're executing the loadPage function immediately! setTimeout expects a function to be executed later on. (the -1 was not mine indeed)

Comment: jQuery aside - you are correct, it was not working. Forgot to pass the function as a string. Fixed the code and the fiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to include jQuery to run this code, but this is the idea

```
<a href="http://www.url.com">Click Me</a>
$("a").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    location.replace(url);
  }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: >You'll need to include jQuery< Eummmm why you need to include jQuery ?

Comment: Because over 75% of the web development community already includes jQuery.

Comment: and who says 75% use jQuery ?? besides that.. OP ask for JS ;-)

Comment: #1 Okay, 77% of the *top 1 million websites* use jQuery, sorry (http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/jQuery). There are other polls that I have seen that have interviewed thousands of developers and jQuery usage was in the 70-80% range. #2, jQuery is javascript.. lol

Comment: >#2  jQuery is javascript <  eum JQuery is a library .. javascript is a framework...

Comment: >#1 77% uses jQuery.. so 230.000 website that not use jQuery is a non-important number ??

Comment: Dude What is your beef? jQuery is simply a library of functions that allow you to write cleaner **javascript** code.. everything jQuery executes is still javascript code, so what is your point? You're arguing semantics like some ridiculous pissing contest. OP just wanted help. He never even asked for a JS solution until someone told him he would need JS, so jQuery was not out of the question at that point. Recommending jQuery to a beginner is not a bad idea either considering A. it has a ton of support, and B. raw javascript is very cumbersome, redundant, and confusing to a new coder.

Answer (score -1):

This way:

HTML

```
<span id="link" data-href="http://www.google.it">click here</span>
```

JS

```
$('#link').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = $('#link').attr('data-href');
    }, 10000);
});
```